# How do I install an Xbee? I am trying to do it with ruby

Tags: ruby, arduino

Download the ruby-xbee tarball from [Here](http://www.esawdust.com/ruby-xbee/releases/ruby-xbee-1.0/ruby-xbee-1.0.tar.gz.).  Extracted the bundle into its permanent directory:

```
cd to /ruby*pcc
```

I Did

```
$ ln -s ruby-serial-port-0.6-linux-intel ruby-serialport-0.6
$ ruby extconf.rb
```

worked ok. Made a MakeFile

```
$ make
```

I got multiple errors in serial.c, did not get to

```
$ make install
```

I tried these things

```
gedit serialport.c
```

Change

```
#include <rubyio.h>
```

to

```
#include <ruby/io.h>
```

and

```
sudo gem install serialport
```

Answer (score 1):

I got X-CTU to work in Wine. Those instructions are [here](http://wire.less.dk/?p=162)

After installing Wine, add these symlinks

In `~/.wine/dosdevices`, do

```
ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 com5
ln -s /dev/ttyUSB1 com6
ln -s /dev/ttyUSB2 com7
ln -s /dev/ttyUSB3 com8
```

I actually had to do

```
sudo ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 com5
```

in `/dev` which is different than in the directions.

After that download the XCTU exe (on linked page).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.